# How does Intimidating Rage interact with Imperious Command?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The text for Imperious Command reads:

> If you successfully demoralize a foe in combat, the foe cowers in fear for 1 round and is shaken in the following round.

and the Intimidating Rage feat:

> While you are raging, you designate a single foe within 30feet of you that you can attempt to demoralize as a free action (see the intimidate skill page 76 of the Player's Handbook). A foe that you successfully demoralize remains shaken for as long as you continue to rage. You may only use this feat against a single foe in any particular encounter.

As I see it, there are 3 options when using both feats together:

1. The foe is cowered for 1 round and then shaken for the duration of the rage.
2. The foe is cowered for the duration of the rage and then shaken 1 round
3. The foe is cowered for 1 round, frightened for 1 round and then shaken for the duration of the rage (due to the two shaken effects stacking)?

So, which on is the correct interpretation?

Comment: What does “most extended” mean? You used the same in your previous question, and I assumed it was just a typo for “most intended” or something, but now I’m not so sure.

Comment: Well if there are different interpretations and no clear RAW the one which is most common among DMs, but thinking about it maybe I should just remove that part.

Comment: Probably; that’s pretty much the default around here anyway. And “most extended” doesn’t mean that in any event.

Comment: Probably should remove it. It's nearly impossible to accurately survey RPG groups to find out anything like that objectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To review:

- The default rules for demoralizing require a standard action and apply a 1-round shaken effect.
- Intimidating Rage changes this to require a free action, and for the shaken effect to last as long as you rage.
- Imperious Command changes the 1 round of shaken to 1 round of cowering followed by 1 round of shaken.

These two options *replace* some of the rules for demoralize; they are not applied as two separate effects. So the target will definitely not be frightened at any point; you will not be applying two separate shaken conditions. Unfortunately, that’s the last statement we can make with certainty.

How and whether you can apply two replacement effects to the same thing is not defined in the rules.

You could argue that they are both replacing the same thing, the rules for demoralizing, and cannot be used together at all.

You could argue that they are both replacing the same, but that thing is just the *effect* of demoralizing (and, in this argument, the fact that Intimidating Rage *also* replaces the action cost is a separate and thus irrelevant replacement). In this view, you could take advantage of Intimidating Rage’s lower action cost and combine that with Imperious Command’s effect, but you would still get only 1 round of cowering and 1 round of shaken.

You could argue that they don’t change the same thing, as Intimidating Rage is changing the duration of the shaken effect while Imperious Command is inserting a round of cowering first, so you get 1 round of cowering followed by them being shaken as long as you rage.

Any of these has validity, and might be true. There are not enough details to say. You’ll have to ask your DM. Ultimately, Intimidating Rage is replicating a lot of the default rules for demoralize in its own text, and it’s unclear how much of that is just a reminder of how everything it’s not changing work, or if those are reiterations of those rules to somehow “enforce” them in the face of other options (like Imperious Command).

On a complete side-note, if you’re interested in demoralizing, you should also look into Never Outnumbered from *Complete Scoundrel*. Though you would have even more confusion about how or whether it could combine with Intimidating Rage.

Comment: I will definately be using the Never Outnumbered skill trick but that looks less confusing to me: everything you do to a foe, you do to everyone in a 10' radius, with separate save rolls. The only tricky thing is the 10' radius around a square (and not a corner).

Comment: @skd It causes confusion because Intimidating Rage specifies a single chosen target per rage. It’s unclear if Never Outnumbered can or does override that.

Comment: Oh, I see. Never Outnumbered does not say anything about the source of the intimidation and I always interpreted Intimidating Rage as giving you a free Intimidate Check when you rage.

Comment: @Weaveworker89 Unless Never Outnumbered changes that rule. That’s what options in this game do, they let you “cheat” and break the previously-established rules. There is no definitive reason Intimidating Rage should “win” here.

Comment: They replace different things and might stack like this: intimidating rage -> action to free/ duration of shaken effect; imperious command: improves condition to cower for 1 round then decreases do shaken; never outnumbered: increases number of targets. So you have a demoralizing effect that is a free action to activate, affects more targets, causes the condition cowering for a round and then shaken for as long as you rage.

Comment: @Victor And you have, I assume, something to back up your assertion that it works precisely that way, and not any of the other plausible ways the rules can be interpreted as I outlined in my answer?

Comment: @KRyan Yes. Based on the rulings of each item, Intimidating rage allows you to use the demoralize action as the intimidate skill when you enter a rage. Never outnumbered modifies the number of targets you can affect when you demoralize via the intimidate skill, tehrefore modifying the number of targets. Then we have the imperious command feat that states if you demoralize a foe in combat it becomes cowered and then shaken. Also the intimidating rage comes in play again because it alters the duration of the shaken effect. This is based on RAW.

Comment: @Victor And that’s entirely plausible but not *uniquely plausible*. As I say in my answer, other interpretations are *also* plausible, even under the strictest RAW. The rules as written never define exactly how such replacements work or how much they can be interleaved. The request was for evidence that the other interpretations I mark as plausible actually are not plausible.

Comment: @KRyan I understood what you said but I sustain what I said earlier. So I'll try to refute your other statements: 1) They both modify the rule for demoralize so they cant be used togheter. - This corolary is false because there is nowhere in the rules that says you can't modify an ability only once since they are not replacing it with a new ability (like trading a class feature away), so you can stack modifications. 2) This statement I can agree with, because of the wording of the imperious command,this is the only gray area and is up to RAI, although I still sustain my opinion.

Comment: @Victor Ah, my apologies; I was unclear. I meant that you should do so in your own answer. Either you are right and/or more convincing (at which point you deserve the reputation that comes from it, not me), or else you are wrong or less convincing (in which case I should not edit my answer). So in neither case does it make sense for me to edit my answer—you should write your own. That will give you the room to address the question fully (which you must do; addressing my answer and not the question is against the rules), and give others a chance to weigh in.